# Prelaunchr mailer not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am running Harry's prelaunchr (https://github.com/harrystech/prelaunchr) on Heroku and the welcome email that is supposed to send out when a new user signs up on the site is not sending out. The rails app is using Delayed::Job and when I run

```
heroku rake jobs:work
```

I get the following output:

```
 Rendered user_mailer/signup_email.html.erb (1.2ms)
[Worker(host:46d2c895-5e66-464b-8594-510461de915c pid:3)] Class#signup_email failed with ActionView::Template::Error: undefined method `encoding' for {:host=>"windreturns.com"}:Hash - 9 failed attempts
```

^Note: host=>"windreturns.com" is my domain, but it is not where the site is currently located (it's a genericname.herokuapp.com domain)

Any idea why the jobs are failing? How do I get the emails to send?

Comment: in your production env `   config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { :host => 'www.example.com' }` what is set here which is using in mailer view

Comment: config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { :host => 'windreturns.com' } is set in production...is that why it is not working?

Comment: please replace it with `ActionMailer::Base.action_mailer.default_url_options = {:host => request.host_with_port}` in before_filter

Comment: I replaced the line: `config.action_mailer.default_url_options  = { :host => 'www.example.com' }`

with: 'ActionMailer::Base.action_mailer.default_url_options = {:host => request.host_with_port}'

got thiswhen precompile assets:

'Admins-MacBook-Air:prelaunch admin$ RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake assets:precompile
assets:precompile:all RAILS_ENV=production RAILS_GROUPS=assets
rake aborted!
undefined method `action_mailer' for ActionMailer::Base:Class
/Users/admin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p598@prelaunch-app/gems/actionmailer-3.2.11/lib/action_mailer/base.rb:438:in `method_missing''

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I'm having trouble setting this up too.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why, but it seems like the file `app/views/user_mailer/signup_email.html.erb` has several issues, dating back to the [initial commit](https://github.com/harrystech/prelaunchr/commit/13b93ffbbd0733de8655f769fa8c528eb28d26bb#diff-3c185168e330d2c7aaadc10eff5ebdddR20) that had a syntax error in it. The current version is using asset links like this:

```
<%= Rails.application.config.action_mailer.default_url_options %>/assets/logo.jpg
```

The first problem with this is that `default_url_options` is not a string, it's a hash. The second problem is that the email assets are in `/assets/email`. I got the email working by changing the above to:

```
<%= Rails.application.config.action_mailer.default_url_options[:host] %>/assets/email/logo.jpg
```

You have to do this in nine places, then it should work.

Also set something like `DEFAULT_MAILER_HOST="http://localhost:5000"` in your `.env` file.